# How to get the web site assembly from a library

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, ihttphandler

My solution comprises 2 projects, a ASP.NET MVC 3 project -- **Company.Web** and a .NET library project -- **Company.BLL**.  The library contains a class implementing IHTTP -- **Company.BLL.Fido**.

I have registered Fido as an HTTPHandler with my web project and in the ProcessRequest() method I would like to dynamically invoke a method from the Company.Web project -- **Company.Web.FidoHelper.DoSomething()** using reflection.

How do I get a reference to the **Company.Web** assembly?  Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() returns *System.Web*, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returns *null*, and Assembly.GetAssembly() returns *Company.BLL*.

Looking through AppDomain.GetAssemblies(), I see that **Company.Web** is included in the results, but how can my library project know which one to choose?  I can't hard-code that choice since I plan to reuse this library with other projects.

Code:

```
namespace Company.BLL
{
    public class Fido: IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //hard-coding like this is not acceptable
            var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                     .Where(a => a.FullName
                                     .StartsWith("Company.Web"))
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
            var type = assembly.GetType("Company.Web.FidoHelper");
            object appInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.InvokeMember("DoSomething", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, appInstance, new object[] { context });
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Assembly helperAssy = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(FidoHelper));
```

Here's the MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

** **UPDATE** **

Ok, so if you don't have a reference back to `Company.BLL` then you're going to have to go through *all* of the assemblies loaded in the AppDomain.  It will be messy because you're going to have to look through names and such to find what you want.

But something like this:

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.Current.GetAssemblies();
Assembly theOne;
foreach(Assembly assy in assemblies)
{
   if(assy.FullName == "Company.Web")
   {
       theOne = assy;
       break;
   }
}
// Do the rest of your work
```

Comment: Company.BLL doesn't have a reference to Company.Web so I doesn't know about FidoHelper.  The reflection code exists within the Company.BLL.Fido.ProcessRequest() method.

Comment: I can't have a circular reference and hard-coding to a specific type is not desirable since it prevents reusing this code with future projects.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  You **have to** have a concrete implementation on some defined class that you want to execute.  If you want to make a method that accepts the assembly name, the class name, and the method name as parameters that's simple enough to do.

Comment: Agreed.  If this weren't an ASP.NET app, the problem would be easily solved.  I'm hoping someone can point me toward a solution I've overlooked, perhaps deepening my understanding of ASP.NET internals.  Otherwise, it looks like this approach is FUBAR.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem:

In **Company.Web**, create a class **Fido** which extends **Company.BLL.Fido**.  Don't provide any implementation and register **Company.Web.Fido** as the the handler instead of **Company.BLL.Fido**.

In **Company.BLL.Fido's** ProcessRequest() method, the HTTP context's *CurrentHandler* property now references **Company.Web.Fido** so I can get a reference to the **Company.Web** assembly using that type.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(context.CurrentHandler.GetType()); 
//assembly = Company.Web
```

Now, I can use reflection to invoke Company.Web.FidoHelper.DoSomething(context).

Code:

```
namespace Company.BLL
{
    public class Fido: IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //hard-coding like this is not acceptable
            var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(context.CurrentHandler.GetType());
            var type = assembly.GetType("Company.Web.FidoHelper");
            object appInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.InvokeMember("DoSomething", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, appInstance, new object[] { context });
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OOps, the type name is now hard-coded.  I think I might have to create a section in the configuration file and specify the FQ type there.  This would be better anyway b/c I wouldn't then require Company.Web to implement a derived HTTP handler type.